# Neovim&deoplete-jediでAnacondaを使いたいのですが、エラーを消せません。

Tags: python, vim, anaconda

Pythonコーディングで、Neovimにてdeoplete-jediの補完を行いつつ、ライブラリはvirtualenvのAnacondaを参照していきたいのですが、うまくいきません。

環境はWindows10のBash on Windowsです。(Ubuntu16.0.4)
neovimの:CheckHealth画面は下記の状態。

[image: neovim :CheckHealth画面]

pyenv virtualenvにAnaconda3-4.4.0の仮想環境を構築し、そこのフルパスを指定しています。
エラーはneovimでpython3を使うためには、別途モジュールをインストールする必要がある、という内容だと思うのですが、`pip3 install neovim` (sudoでも)をやってもダメでした。
※Python2系は現状使わないのでスルーしてます。スルーNGでしたらご指摘いただけますと。

```
Requirement already satisfied: neovim in /home/～/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

と、既にインストールされてるよとでてきます。しかし、このインストール先が

```
~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

となっているのが原因だと思っています。が、どうすればいいのか分かりません。
virtualenvに入ったあとに `pip3 install neovim` をしても結果は変わりません。

どうすればAnacondaの中にNeovimのモジュールを持ってこれるのでしょうか？

環境を作る際にやったことは以下の通りです。

```
pyenv virtualenv anaconda3-4.4.0 neovim3
pyenv shell neovim-3
let g:python3_host_prog=$PYENV_ROOT.'/versions/neovim-3/bin/python'
```

Anacondaが5.0.0でないのは、なぜかpyenvでインストールがうまくいかないからです。

Comment: CirocMK2さん、ご回答ありがとうございます！早速試してみます。

Comment: この質問は解決済みでは無く、プラス票の多い回答も無いので、これからもシステムにより繰り返しトップページに流されることになります。質問が回答により解決しているならば、「承認」という操作を行なって下さい。詳しくは[「自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をご覧下さい。自己解決している場合は、自分自身で回答を書き、その回答を承認して下さい。詳しくは[「自分の質問に回答できますか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をご覧下さい。解決していないならば、回答に示された方法でうまくいかなかった点を質問に追記して下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let g:python3_host_prog=$PYENV_ROOT.'/versions/neovim-3/bin/python'

ここの｢`｣の位置がおかしいのではないでしょうか｡

> let g:python3_host_prog='$PYENV_ROOT/versions/neovim-3/bin/python'

似たようなことで苦しんだのですが､フルパスで書くと私はうまくいきました

[neovimのCheckHealthでpython2がpython3を見に行ってしまってます｡](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/39911/)

あとは`neovim-3`をactivateしたあとに､`pip install neovim`をやってanaconda3環境でneovimモジュールをインストールする必要があります｡

https://qiita.com/lighttiger2505@github/items/4c6807b7508afe7d4a07
これの後半に､py2,py3でそれぞれモジュールインストールして､init.vimにパスを追加する手順があるので､そこをanacondaに変えればいいと思います