# neovimのCheckHealthでpython2がpython3を見に行ってしまう

Tags: python, vim, neovim

`INFO: Python2 version: 3.6.3↲`となってしまうのは何故でしょうか｡
virtualenvでpy2用のneovim2とpy3用のneovim3は作っています｡

```
health#provider#check↲
========================================================================↲
## Clipboard (optional)↲
  - OK: Clipboard tool found: pbcopy↲
↲
## Python 2 provider (optional)↲
  - OK: pyenv found: "/Users/okamura/dotfiles/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv"↲
  - INFO: Using: g:python_host_prog = "~/.pyenv/versions/neovim2/bin/python"↲
  - INFO: Executable: /Users/okamura/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/bin/python↲
  - WARNING: Unexpected Python version. This could lead to confusing error messages.↲
  - INFO: Python2 version: 3.6.3↲
  - INFO: python-neovim version: 0.2.0↲
  - OK: Latest python-neovim is installed: 0.2.0↲
↲
## Python 3 provider (optional)↲
  - OK: pyenv found: "/Users/okamura/dotfiles/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv"↲
  - INFO: Using: g:python3_host_prog = "~/.pyenv/versions/neovim3/bin/python"↲
  - INFO: Executable: /Users/okamura/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/bin/python↲
  - INFO: Python3 version: 3.6.3↲
  - INFO: python-neovim version: 0.2.0↲
  - OK: Latest python-neovim is installed: 0.2.0↲
```

`.config/nvim/init.vim`には下記の2行を記載しています｡

```
let g:python_host_prog = '~/.pyenv/versions/neovim2/bin/python'↲
let g:python3_host_prog = '~/.pyenv/versions/neovim3/bin/python'
```

Answer (score 1):

すいません自己解決しました｡`python_host_prog`をフルパスにしたら治りました

```
health#provider#check↲
========================================================================↲
## Clipboard (optional)↲
  - OK: Clipboard tool found: pbcopy↲
↲
## Python 2 provider (optional)↲
  - OK: pyenv found: "/Users/okamura/dotfiles/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv"↲
  - INFO: Using: g:python_host_prog = "/Users/okamura/dotfiles/.pyenv/versions/neovim2/bin/python"↲
  - INFO: Executable: /Users/okamura/dotfiles/.pyenv/versions/neovim2/bin/python↲
  - INFO: Python2 version: 2.7.14↲
  - INFO: python-neovim version: 0.2.0↲
  - OK: Latest python-neovim is installed: 0.2.0↲
↲
## Python 3 provider (optional)↲
  - OK: pyenv found: "/Users/okamura/dotfiles/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv"↲
  - INFO: Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/Users/okamura/dotfiles/.pyenv/versions/neovim3/bin/python"↲
  - INFO: Executable: /Users/okamura/dotfiles/.pyenv/versions/neovim3/bin/python↲
  - INFO: Python3 version: 3.6.3↲
  - INFO: python-neovim version: 0.2.0↲
  - OK: Latest python-neovim is installed: 0.2.0↲
```